# Разделить значение из строки php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код:

`$text = "25-117";`

Как вывести отдельно 25 и 117.
Количество символов в неизвестно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию `explode` (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) и получите массив

```
<?php
$text = "25-117";
$arr = explode('-', $text);

print_r($arr);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/996d160a6d13ace8f52985345fd130453f4dccdd

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "25-117";
$pos  = strpos($text, "-");

$t1   = substr($text, 0, $pos);
$t2   = substr($text, $pos + 1);
```

функция `strpos()` определит позицию символа `-`, затем функции `substr()` возвратят часть перед и после этого символа.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$string = "25-117";
$string = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/i', ' ', $string); // убираем всё кроме чисел

$array = explode(' ', $string); // создаём массив

print_r($array[0]."<br>");
print_r($array[1]."<br>");
?>
```